# How can I use ansible.builtin.git for creating local branch and pushing code to git repo?

Tags: git, ansible

I need to perform the following steps in using ansible playbook:

1. I need to clone a repository,
2. Make some changes to a file in that repository
3. Checkout the changes to a new branch locally
4. Commit the change and push to remote repository

For cloning I am able to do this

```yaml
 - name: CloneTeamRepoisitory
   ansible.builtin.git:
    repo: 'git@github.abcd.com:myrepo/my-team.git'
    dest: '{{ TMPDIR }}'
    clone: yes
    update: no
    accept_hostkey: yes
```

After this I make some file changes through copy command

Now I need to checkout to a git branch locally the changes I did in the previous step:

```
### if it's the first time you are using this customer's branch:
git checkout -b <teamname>
#### all subsequent times
git checkout <teamname>
####
git add <teamname>
git commit -m "Adding team <newteamname>"
### First time push
git push --set-upstream origin <team>
### Afterwards first time subsequent push:
git push
```

For this step, I am not aware I can do it with the `ansible.builtin.git` module. Is there any way I can accomplish my requirement using a dedicated Ansible module?

Comment: `Is there any way I can accomplish my requirement using a dedicated Ansible module?` <= short answer: no. Ansible `git` module first intent is to manage checkouts to deploy software on a target, not to run any complicated git workflow. You would have to do this through `shell` or `command`.